# How to display summary content from a Page (Not a Post) on another page

Tags: wp-query, pages, frontpage

I created a Page called "About Joe" as a ***page*** in WordPress.

Then on a different page (e.g. the homepage), I wish to display *a summary* which includes:

1. a thumbnail
2. the 1st paragraph
3. link to page

Is this possible?

Maybe I'm not asking the right questions to the codex as I'm not finding anything.

The closest thing I could find was `get_page()`, which i'm not even sure is the solution.

But that function is now ***deprecated***.

Please advise!

Thanks

Comment: OK. WP_Query looks like where I need to be. Checking...

Comment: yep. WP_Query does just what i'm looking for (mostly).

Comment: What do you mean by mostly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: No more working tired!** Completely forgot about WP_Query. Here is what I came up with...

```
<?php
    $args = array (
        'page_id'             => '1265',
        'post_type'           => 'Page',
        'post_status'         => 'published',
        'posts_per_page'      => '1',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    );

    // The Query
    $fa_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $fa_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $fa_query->have_posts() ) : $fa_query->the_post(); ?>
    // do something
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    // Nothing to see
<?php endif; ?>                     
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$post = get_post( id );` and then set the post like `setup_postdata($post);` and you can call `the_content();` or `the_excerpt();`

Comment: To reset the postdata use wp_reset_postdata();